# Авторизация в instagram на selenium

Tags: python, pyqt5, selenium, gui, pyqt

Есть окно входа и скрипт авторизации инстаграм на селениум , вот реализация:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver
import time 
import random
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
import os
import re
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore,QtGui,QtWidgets 
from des import * 

class InstagramBot():
    def __init__(self,username,password):
       self.username = username
       self.password = password
       options = Options()
       # options.add_argument("--headless")
       self.browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)

    def close_browser(self):

        self.browser.close()
        self.browser.quit()

    def login(self):
        browser = self.browser
        browser.get('https://www.instagram.com/')
        time.sleep(random.randrange(4 ,6))

        username_input = browser.find_element_by_name("username") 
        username_input.clear()
        username_input.send_keys(username)

        time.sleep(5)
        password_input = browser.find_element_by_name("password") 
        password_input.clear()
        password_input.send_keys(password)

        password_input =browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body
        /div[1]/section
        /main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div
        /div[3]/button/div").click()
        time.sleep(10)

class GUI(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QTabWidget.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.username = self.ui.lineEdit.text()
        self.password = self.ui.lineEdit_2.text()
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.go_to)

    def go_to(self):
        self.ui.lineEdit.clear()
        self.ui.lineEdit_2.clear()
        username = self.username
        password = self.password
        self.inst = InstagramBot(username,password)
        self.inst.login()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        mywin = GUI()
        mywin.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Но я никак не могу вытащить переменные из функции `go_to` и  вставить их в класс с ботом для авторизации

Answer (score 2, accepted):

я не могу проверить ваш пример, но предложу проверить следующее:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver
import time 
import random
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
import os
import re
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets 
from des import *                                                   # ???


class InstagramBot():
    def __init__(self, username, password):
    
       self.username = username
       self.password = password
       print(self.username, self.password)                          # проверьте, что там
       
       options = Options()
       # options.add_argument("--headless")
       self.browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)

    def close_browser(self):
        self.browser.close()
        self.browser.quit()

    def login(self):
        browser = self.browser
        browser.get('https://www.instagram.com/')
        time.sleep(random.randrange(4 ,6))

        username_input = browser.find_element_by_name("username") 
        username_input.clear()

#                                 ????????        
#        username_input.send_keys(username)
        username_input.send_keys(self.username)                          # +

        time.sleep(5)
        password_input = browser.find_element_by_name("password") 
        password_input.clear()

#                                 ????????        
#        password_input.send_keys(password)
        password_input.send_keys(self.password)                          # +

        password_input = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body
        /div[1]/section
        /main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div
        /div[3]/button/div").click()
        time.sleep(10)


class GUI(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
#                  vvvvvvvvvv                                           # <--- ???     
#        QtWidgets.QTabWidget.__init__(self)
        super().__init__()                                              # +
        
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        
#        self.username = self.ui.lineEdit.text()
#        self.password = self.ui.lineEdit_2.text()
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.go_to)
        
    def go_to(self):
#        self.ui.lineEdit.clear()
#        self.ui.lineEdit_2.clear()
#        username = self.username
#        password = self.password

        username = self.ui.lineEdit.text()                              # +
        password = self.ui.lineEdit_2.text()                            # +
        self.ui.lineEdit.clear()                                        # +
        self.ui.lineEdit_2.clear()                                      # +
        
        self.inst = InstagramBot(username, password)
        self.inst.login()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mywin = GUI()
    mywin.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое за помощь в реализации задумки , я обязательно проверю и скажу что получилось)

Comment: вы просто мой спаситель , все работает , перекину selenium в поток чтоб программа не зависала и продолжу дальше писать , спасибо вам большое)